# Eager Loading with Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

In my rails app, **projects** have many **steps**, and steps can have **questions**

I'd like to write a method that checks whether a project has any questions and return the id of the step with the question.

Currently, I have the following in my **project.rb**

```
 def step_with_question
    question_step = ""
    steps.order(:published_on).each do |step|
      if step.question
        question_step = step.id
      end
    end
    return question_step
  end
```

But I think this is inefficient and think there is probably a much faster way to do this with eager loading (this creates a query for every step in the project).  Does anyone have advice for how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `joins` to only return associated `:steps` which actually have `:questions` associations with them:

```
@project = Project.joins(steps: :questions).order('steps.published_on').find(id)
```

This query will return only the project steps that actually have an associated question. You can now safely loop through the steps records and return or use `step.id`

```
@project.steps.each do |step|
  question_step = step.id
  # do something with the question_step
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what your code does exactly, but if you want to access a Question, from a Step, you can use the method `includes`:

```
project = Project.find(id) # Get a product just to show how it works
# To tell Rails to make a single query when you want to
# access the questions, do something like this:
steps_with_questions = project.steps.includes(:question)
```

This way, when you try to access a question, it'll be already loaded.

The best way to work with these is to write a scope for `step.rb`, like this:

```
scope :with_questions, lambda { includes :questions }
```

Now you only need to call:

```
project.steps.with_questions
```

Making the code a lot easier to read.

EDIT: Your code would look like this: (without the scope I mentioned earlier)

```
 def step_with_question
    question_step = ""
    steps.order(:published_on).includes(:question).each do |step|
      if step.question
        question_step = step.id
      end
    end
    return question_step
  end
```

Comment: you might consider has_many :through to associate questions with projects